# How can I lock twice with the same mutex on the same thread?

Tags: c++, mutex, recursive-mutex

I have this class (simplified):

```
// thing.h

#include <mutex>

class Thing
{
public:
    void process();
    void inner();

private:
    std::mutex lock;
};

// thing.cpp

#include "Thing.h"

using namespace std;

void Thing::process()
{
    lock_guard<mutex> locking(lock);

    inner();
}

void Thing::inner()
{
    lock_guard<mutex> locking(lock);
}
```

If I make a call to process, I get an exception:

```
Microsoft C++ exception: std::system_error at memory location 0x006FF16C.
```

Locking on the same lock in the same thread causes this exception. How can I do this without the exception? I thought about adding a flag:

```
volatile bool alreadyLocked;
```

Changing inner to:

```
void Thing::inner()
{
     if (!alreadyLocked)
     {
         lock_guard<mutex> locking(lock);
         alreadyLocked = true;
         ...something magic happens here...
         alreadyLocked = false;
     }
}
```

However this feels brittle... is there a right way to do this?

Comment: You could move the "magic" to a new private function, and call it from the two public ones. Then they wouldn't have to call each other.

Comment: You should really resort to redesigning you code. Try separating the locking from any logic and everything will become much simpler. For instance you could wrap the class that does the 'magic' into some adapter that is only responsible for handling locks, and what not. This way you won't have to worry about mutexes in your logic.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Firstly, `volatile` variables **are NOT thread-safe**. You must use `std::atomic<T>` to have thread-safe variables. `volatile` has nothing to do with thread safety.

To solve your issue, you can use [`std::recursive_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex), which can be locked/unlocked multiple times from the same thread.

From cppreference:

> A calling thread owns a `recursive_mutex` for a period of time that starts when it successfully calls either `lock` or `try_lock`. During this period, the thread may make additional calls to `lock` or `try_lock`. The period of ownership ends when the thread makes a matching number of calls to unlock.
>
> When a thread owns a `recursive_mutex`, all other threads will block (for calls to `lock`) or receive a false return value (for `try_lock`) if they attempt to claim ownership of the `recursive_mutex`.

---

Additionally, please consider refactoring your code so that locking a mutex twice is not required. Improving your design could probably avoid this issue.

Comment: +1 for the last note. In most cases locking a mutex multiple times is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)

Answer (score 4):

There is a coding hack to get around this design problem; it’s called a recursive mutex. But you really should fix the design problem, not try to work around it. Separate your code into two layers: all the work inside your class should be done by private member functions that don’t lock anything; the external interface should be implemented through public member functions, and **they** lock the mutex.

So:

```
class Thing {
public:
    void process();
    void inner();
private:
    void do_process();
    void do_inner();
    std::mutex mtx;
};

void Thing::process() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    do_process();
}

void Thing::inner() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    do_inner();
}

void Thing::do_process() {
    do_inner();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The solution is to use `std::recursive_mutex` instead of `std::mutex`.**

Other answers have already given the correct solution, but I would like to point out two other things:

1. Just because `volatile` was not designed for thread safety, it doesn't mean it has nothing to do with thread safety. In the original post, `volatile bool alreadyLocked;` is correct and enough.
2. This is by no means a "code smell"! When a system gets complex, recursive lock to a mutex is sometimes inevitable. If this were a "code smell" or could be resolved by a better design, the `std::recursive_mutex` would be a joke and should be dumped out of the C++ standard library. But it is still there, why?